# Using arrow keys in vb.net to send data to an arduino over serial

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

I've used another variation of this code to send arrow presses as data over tcp/ip and udp. I'm trying to send arrow press info to an arduino over serial. This code has worked fine for me in the past but I get the following error message whenever I try to compile my vb.net project "Error    1   'SerialPort1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  C:\Users\chris.FTKNOCKS\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication8\WindowsApplication8\Form1.vb  10  9   WindowsApplication8" I get one of these errors for every instance of Serial1 in the program if anyone has any ideas ort suggestions I'd appreciate it.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Shared _continue As Boolean
    Shared _serialPort As SerialPort

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SerialPort1.Close()
        SerialPort1.PortName = "com14" 'change com port to match your Arduino port
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
        SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
        SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
        SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default 'very important!
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
            SerialPort1.Open()
            SerialPort1.Write("0")
            SerialPort1.Close()
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
            SerialPort1.Open()
            SerialPort1.Write("1")
            SerialPort1.Close()
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            SerialPort1.Open()
            SerialPort1.Write("2")
            SerialPort1.Close()
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
            SerialPort1.Open()
            SerialPort1.Write("3")
            SerialPort1.Close()
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Dim keydelay As Integer = 0
End Class
```

Comment: Looks like there's no SerialPort1 object.  Drop it onto the form surface.  If its already there, check that the name of the component is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't that be handled by  Imports System.IO.Ports

Comment: You were absolutely correct.  I'm used to python and c.

Comment: `SerialPort` lives in the `System.IO.Ports` namespace, yes.  But its not a shared class (shared methods).  You must instantiate it.  `SerialPort1` is that instance.  You can tell its a WinForms component because of the naming convention (class name + number).